# How to create external table to DynamoDB on Hive 3.1

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-dynamodb

I'd like to know if it's possible to have an external table pointing to a DynamoDB table on AWS using Hive.
I'm not using AWS EMR, what I'm using is a Hadoop Stack configured through Apache Ambari.

Hive version: Hive 3.1.0.3.1.4.0-315

What I did was:
Downloaded the EMR Dynamo-Hive connector JARS directly from the maven repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazon.emr

I loaded all the JARS in hive.aux.jars.path:

```
emr-dynamodb-hadoop-4.12.0.jar
emr-dynamodb-hive-4.12.0.jar
emr-dynamodb-tools-4.12.0.jar
hive1.2-shims-4.12.0.jar
hive1-shims-4.12.0.jar
hive2-shims-4.12.0.jar
hive2-shims-4.15.0.jar
shims-common-4.12.0.jar
shims-loader-4.12.0.jar
```

But when I try to create the table with:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dynamo_LabDynamoHive
    (id double, nome string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' 
TBLPROPERTIES (
    "dynamodb.table.name" = "LabDynamoHive", 
    "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "id:id,nome:nome"
);
```

I get the following error:

```
INFO  : Starting task [Stage-0:DDL] in serial mode
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: Shim class for Hive version 3.1.1000 does not exist
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20200422142624_6ebabdc8-8942-4025-84a8-411505d20895); Time taken: 0.203 seconds
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: Shim class for Hive version 3.1.1000 does not exist (state=08S01,code=1)
```

I know I'm not loading a Shims JAR for Hive 3, but I'd like to know if any of you have tried and succeded in using an external table with DynamoDB using Hive 3 outside of EMR.

Any help or directions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

problem is apparently the source code of this EMR connector is somewhat outdated and lacks Hive 3.x support recently introduced by AWS for EMR 6.0.

However, you can find a working 3.1 implementation here, forked from the official EMR connector: https://github.com/ramsesrm/emr-dynamodb-connector

Installation steps as follow:
1- compile the mentioned code (mvn clean package)
2- install the 3 JARs in your hive.aux.jars.path, along with aws-java-sdk-core and aws-java-sdk-dynamodb JARs from AWS (shim JARs are not required), 5 in total.

Tha's it. Don't forget to specify the region as a TBLPROPERTIES if you're not using the default US one.